# Friendly url - url routing

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-routing

I have a blog site.I have main categories and articles for each category. Each article and category have a id and queries process for these id's. I want to change my url system to friendly urls.

For example:

When click a category you will redirect to  http://aliturgutbozkurt.com/ShowArticles.aspx?AnaId=12

AnaId= MainId here. but i want it to be like http://aliturgutbozkurt.com/C-Sharp

how can i change the all url system?